# OpenCV leaks memory (cvResize, cvCreateImage)

Tags: c, opencv, memory, memory-leaks

I'm running OpenCV on a RaspberryPi and use OpenCVs C interface.

I need to resize the dimensions of an image from a webcam, therefore I used the `cvResize()` function.

It works fine but after a few seconds I run out of memory, since I'm executing the code inside a `while(1)`-Loop and read about other people having this problem, I suspect a memory leak.

Here is my code:

```
IplImage *frame;
IplImage *frameRaw;

main() {
    CvCapture *capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(-1);

    while (1) {
        frameRaw = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT), frameRaw->depth, frameRaw->nChannels);

        cvResize(frameRaw, frame, 0); // 0 = CV_INTER_NEAREST

        // Do something with "frame"
    }

}
```

I already tried to free the reserved memory at the end of each iteration using `cvReleaseImage(&frameRaw)` (or `&frame`) but that always caused a segmentation fault. Using `cvReleaseImageHeader()` caused no segmentation fault but also didn't free any memory.

Also I tried to change the capture-resolution of the frames via `cvSetCaptureProperty()` but that did nothing.

Can someone help me understand what's going wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using an additional library? I can't find any mention anywhere of cvFreeImage or cvFreeImageHeader. Do you mean cvReleaseImage()?

Comment: The code you show is definitely missing a `cvReleaseImage` call, to go with the `cvCreateImage` -- you always allocate, never deallocate. Also, you shouldn't be deallocating `frameRaw`, the docs of `cvQueryFrame` explicitly mention that.

Comment: @bennji_of_the_overflow you're right, I meant `cvReleaseImage()`, seems like it's getting too late for me...

Comment: Thank you very much @DanMašek seems like just using `cvReleaseImage(&frame)` after each iteration solved  the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DanMašek I found the solution:

After each `while`-loop iteration the allocated memory for the frame has to be freed. That can be accomplished using `cvReleaseImage(&frame)`.

The complete code now looks like this:

```
IplImage *frame;
IplImage *frameRaw;

main() {
    CvCapture *capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(-1);

    while (1) {
        frameRaw = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT), frameRaw->depth, frameRaw->nChannels);

        cvResize(frameRaw, frame, 0); // 0 = CV_INTER_NEAREST

        // Do something with "frame"

        cvReleaseImage(&frame);
    }

}
```